# BeautifulSoup not showing correct Unicode character

Tags: html, python-3.x, unicode, beautifulsoup, html-entities

I've been working on a Python script that scrapes a lyrics website to get the frequency of words in bands' albums. This is my first experience with web scraping, so forgive me in advance for my lack of knowledge. I am using Python 3.3.3 and BeautifulSoup 4.

It's working for the most part, but it's not handling the conversion from HTML entities to Unicode characters the way I want.

For example, one of the words on a particular album is déjà. When I ran the code below...

```
band = "protestthehero"
album = "volition"

response = requests.get('http://www.darklyrics.com/lyrics/'+band+'/'+album+'.html')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
[s.extract() for s in soup('h3')]                   #remove h3 tags (song titles)
lyrics = soup.select('div.lyrics');                 #select the lyrics class
[div.extract() for div in lyrics[0].findAll('div')] #remove nested divs
[a.extract() for a in lyrics[0].findAll('a')]       #remove links

lyrics_string = str(lyrics[0]) #convert to a string
print(lyrics_string)
```

...déjà was printed as dÃ©jÃ, which wasn't right at all. Looking at the HTML entities that BeautifulSoup used to get these characters, it seems that it was originally the sequence below:

```
d&Atilde;&copy;j&Atilde;
```

This makes sense, but I'm just confused as to why the website converted déjà to this. My guess is that the website creator just copied the special characters into the HTML page instead of actually using the HTML entities, but I'm not sure. If that's the case, is there no way to get the correct character? I'm kind of at a loss...thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: SOLVED thanks to Jukka. Adding one line to change the response's encoding did the trick

```
response = requests.get('http://www.darklyrics.com/lyrics/'+band+'/'+album+'.html')
response.encoding = "utf-8"
```

☺☺☺☺☺

Comment: The string “dÃ©jÃ ” (where the last character is no-break space) is what you get if you have “déjà” encoded in UTF-8 and the byte string is misinterpreted as iso-8859-1 or windows-1252 encoded. So there is a character encoding problem.

Comment: Saved my life! Apparently the default encoding for requests.get() response is iso-8859-1, so I was able to just set it to utf-8 and it worked like a charm! Wish I could give you top answer.